# How do I find out who called SendMessage?

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg

I'm attempting to debug a problem with my Windows installation. The details don't particularly matter, but I'm looking for the answer to the following question:

> explorer.exe receives a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message. In WinDbg, I can break at the appropriate WndProc. How do I find out who sent the message? That is: is there any way to trace this back to the process that called `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Windows messages are anonymous. Your calling app has no way to determine where they come from unless the message defines some way to identify the sender (which would be easily faked)

Comment: The calling process blocks until the message is delivered. There must, therefore, be an RPC mechanism in play. I know that there's a way to find the caller in a cross-process COM call. I'm wondering whether there's a way to do the same for Windows messages.

Comment: ...and I'm not asking about whether my app can figure it out. I'm asking whether WinDbg can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post may help you perform RPC debugging: http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/remote-procedure-call-debugging/

You will need to enable RPC state gathering: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542974.aspx